# How to match the regex pattern of [...]

Tags: php, html, regex

I am working on wordpress and I need to filter out all the string in this pattern

```
[gallery columns............]
```

For example, if a string like that

```
[gallery columns="3" ids="426,425,427"] abc asdasdsad
```

It should return , notice that the white space between ] and the first character of next string should be remove too (if any)

```
abc asdasdsad
```

Thanks for helping, Tried some regex like `([\[\s\S\] ])` but does not work.

Comment: you want to match `abc asdasdsad` or `[gallery columns="3" ids="426,425,427"]`?

Comment: want go get abc asdasdsad, [gallery columns="3" ids="426,425,427"] is the one I need to filter out e.g. preg_replace()...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use the pattern:

```
/\[.*?\]\s*/
```

The exact statement would be using `preg_replace`:

```
preg_replace( "/\[.*?\]\s*/", "", $str );
```

Answer (score 2):

An alternative solution.
Not regexp but a bit more fun.
Use a combo of stringpos, with substr and a trim :)

```
<?
$string = '[gallery columns="3" ids="426,425,427"] abc asdasdsad';
$pos = strrpos($string, "]");

if ($pos === false) {
  echo "Could not find ']' in string '$string'";
}
else {
  // Grab what you want from the next char position onwards
  $wanted = substr($string, $pos+1);

  // Get rid of starting and end spaces
  trim($wanted);

  // Print out result
  echo "RESULT: $wanted";
}
?>
```

Comment: Or `trim( substr($string, $pos+1) );`

Comment: Nice spot. Expected to do that on refactoring. But to explain the solution with commentary, chose the more verbose path :)

Answer (score 1):

If you are interested only `[...]` then try

```
\[[\s\S]+\]
```

Here is [online demo](http://regex101.com/r/bZ1fN6/5)

---

Get the matched group from index 1 and 2 to match both

```
(\[[\s\S]+\])\s*(.*)
```

Here is [online demo](http://regex101.com/r/bZ1fN6/7)

---

You can use `[^\]]+` instead of `[\s\S]+` as well.

sample code:

```
$re = "/(\\[[^\\]]+\\])\\s*(.*)/";
$str = "[gallery columns=\"3\" ids=\"426,425,427\"] abc asdasdsad";

preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches);
```

Comment: `[\s\S]` is essentially `.`.

Comment: @hjpotter92 you can use `[^\]]+` instead of `[\s\S]+` as well

Answer (score 1):

Use [`strip_shortcodes`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/strip_shortcodes), which is available in WordPress and will take care of any and all edge cases for any and all types of WordPress shortcodes.

Comment: this is a more elegant resolution , hasn't notice wordpress already has this function before, thanks